# How do I update from 12.4 to 13.04?? Macbook alu 2008

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

I can't figure out how to update from 12.04. to 13.04..

I have tried to run update manager, and it says that there nothing to update.

Answer (score 0):

Look for 'Software Sources' on the Dash, and on the last option of the 'Updates' tab (Notify me of a new Ubuntu version) choose 'For any new version'.